# Objects in Array

Tags: php, html, mysql

So i have a SQL call that grabs a set of tags and seperates them by commas with implode and explode but for the link area I would like to use the slug i saved in the db instead of the direct value.

```
$cg;
    $tag=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM wp_pod_tbl_tags");
    while($tags = $tag->fetch_object()){ 
    $ct = explode(",", $categories);
    foreach($ct as $c) {
        if($tags->id == $c) {
            $cg[] = $tags->name;            
        }
    }
}   
    $arrs = implode(", ", $cg);
    $arr = explode(",", $arrs);
    $links = array();.0
    foreach ($arr as $value) {
        $links[] = "<a href='#". trim($value) ."'>". trim($value) ."</a>";
    }
    $links_str = implode(",", $links);
?>
    <span><?=$links_str?></span>
```

Currently it comes out with `<a href=#beer garden>Beer Garden</a>` but in my db i have a slug that is beer-garden. So I would like it to be `<a href="#beer-garden">Beer Garden</a>`. But can't figure out how to add it. To call it would be $tags->slug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get from this `beer-garden` to this `Beer Garden` you need to manipulate the string in two ways:

```
$value = 'beer-garden';
$value = str_replace('-',' ',$value);
$value = ucwords($value);
echo $value; // Beer Garden
```

You will have to adapt it to your situation, on the surface, there may be cases where this doesn't work. Especially when the name is suppose to have a dash.

Comment: Your answer is not the exact answer i am looking for but answered my question. I want the reverse of your answer by adding the dashes. Since I can't use the actual slug. I will just add preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', '-', $value);

Comment: @shayward ah, sorry misread it. Yes, using that regular expression should work.